# c# debugging a method that goes into infinite loop

Tags: c#, winforms

The following code works fine until StepMaker method gives data to modeOffroad where it's like it goes into an infinite loop...

The method should check a 3x3 matrix for a cell that is not obstacle and return it's coordinates to stepmaker that moves the matrix's center to the new coordinates. What makes this error? How could I fix it?

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public class PathFinderOutput
    {
        public byte NextX { get; set; }
        public byte NextY { get; set; }
        public bool Blocked { get; set; }
        public byte CurrentX { get; set; }
        public byte CurrentY { get; set; }
        public byte[,] Map { get; set; }

        public PathFinderOutput(byte nextX, byte nextY, bool blocked, byte currentX, byte currentY, byte[,] map)
        {
            NextX = nextX;
            NextY = nextY;
            Blocked = blocked;
            CurrentX = currentX;
            CurrentY = currentY;
            Map = map;

        }
    }

    public class StepMakerOutput
    {
        public byte CurrentX { get; set; }
        public byte CurrentY { get; set; }

        public StepMakerOutput(byte currentX, byte currentY)
        {
            CurrentX = currentX;
            CurrentY = currentY;
        }
    }

    public byte[,] ObstacleGenerator(byte[,] map, byte leftX, byte rightX, byte TopY, byte bottomY)
    {
        // akadályt építi fel
        for (int i = TopY; i <= bottomY; i++)
        {
            for (int j = leftX; j <= rightX; j++)
            {
                map[i, j] = 1;
            }
        }
        return map;
    }

    public byte[,] MapGenerator()
    {
        // a térképet építi fel
        byte[,] map = new byte[102, 102];
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //a térkép grafikusan nem látható pereme
                if (i == 0 || j == 0 || i == map.GetLength(0) - 1 || j == map.GetLength(1) - 1)
                {
                    map[i, j] = 253;
                }
                else
                //járható út
                {
                    map[i, j] = 0;
                }

            }
        }

        return map;
    }

    public void PictureBuilder(byte[,] map, Graphics g)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < map.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < map.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                //láthatatlan perem
                if (map[i, j] == 0)
                {
                    Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.NavajoWhite;
                    g.FillRectangle(aBrush, i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                //út
                else if (map[i, j] == 253)
                {
                }
                //akadály
                else if (map[i, j] == 1)
                {
                    Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Black;
                    g.FillRectangle(aBrush, i, j, 1, 1);
                }
                //bejárt út
                else if (map[i, j] == 2)
                {
                    Brush aBrush = (Brush)Brushes.Red;
                    g.FillRectangle(aBrush, i, j, 1, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public PathFinderOutput Pathfinder(byte[,] map, StepMakerOutput input, byte endX, byte endY)
    {
        byte distance;
        byte distanceMin = byte.MaxValue;

        byte currentX = input.CurrentX;
        byte currentY = input.CurrentY;
        byte nextX = 1;
        byte nextY = 1;
        bool blocked = false;

        //bejárt utat jelöli meg
        map[currentX, currentY] = 2;

        for (int i = (currentX - 1); i <= currentX + 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = (currentY - 1); j <= currentY + 1; j++)
            {
                //robot saját posízióját ne szkennelje
                if ((i == currentX) && (j == currentY))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                int a = (endX - i) * (endX - i);
                int b = (endY - j) * (endY - j);
                distance = (byte)(Math.Sqrt(a + b));
                if (distanceMin > distance)
                {
                    distanceMin = distance;
                    nextX = (byte)i;
                    nextY = (byte)j;
                    if (map[i, j] == 1)
                    {
                        blocked = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        PathFinderOutput output = new PathFinderOutput(nextX, nextY, blocked, currentX, currentY, map);
        return output;
    }

    public StepMakerOutput ModeOffroad(PathFinderOutput input)
    {
        int xDirection = input.NextX - input.CurrentX;
        int yDirection = input.NextY - input.CurrentY;
        StepMakerOutput temp = new StepMakerOutput(0, 0);

        //az akadály helyzetének megállapítása a robottól nézve
        int switcher = 0;
        if (xDirection == -1 && yDirection == 1)
        {
            switcher = 1;
        } else if (xDirection == 0 && yDirection == 1)
        {
            switcher = 2;
        } else if (xDirection == 1 && yDirection == 1)
        {
            switcher = 3;
        } else if (xDirection == -1 && yDirection == 0)
        {
            switcher = 4;
        } else if (xDirection == 1 && yDirection == 0)
        {
            switcher = 6;
        } else if (xDirection == -1 && yDirection == -1)
        {
            switcher = 7;
        } else if (xDirection == 0 && yDirection == -1)
        {
            switcher = 8;
        } else if (xDirection == + 1 && yDirection == -1)
        {
            switcher = 9;
        }


        //akadálymentes cella keresése
        switch (switcher)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    if (input.Map[input.CurrentX - 1, input.CurrentY + 1] != 1)
                    {
                        temp.CurrentX = (byte)(input.CurrentX - 1);
                        temp.CurrentY = (byte)(input.CurrentY + 1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                        goto case 2;

                }
            case 2:
                {
                    if (input.Map[input.CurrentX + 0, input.CurrentY + 1] != 1)
                    {
                        temp.CurrentX = (byte)(input.CurrentX + 0);
                        temp.CurrentY = (byte)(input.CurrentY + 1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goto case 3;
                    }
                }
            case 3:
                {
                    if (input.Map[input.CurrentX + 1, input.CurrentY + 1] != 1)
                    {
                        temp.CurrentX = (byte)(input.CurrentX + 1);
                        temp.CurrentY = (byte)(input.CurrentY + 1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goto case 6;
                    }
                }
            case 4:
                {
                    if (input.Map[input.CurrentX - 1, input.CurrentY + 0] != 1)
                    {
                        temp.CurrentX = (byte)(input.CurrentX - 1);
                        temp.CurrentY = (byte)(input.CurrentY + 0);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goto case 1;
                    }
                }
            case 6:
                {
                        if (input.Map[input.CurrentX + 1, input.CurrentY + 0] != 1)
                        {
                            temp.CurrentX = (byte)(input.CurrentX + 1);
                            temp.CurrentY = (byte)(input.CurrentY + 0);
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                    {
                        goto case 9;
                    }
                }
            case 7:
                {
                    if (input.Map[input.CurrentX - 1, input.CurrentY - 1] != 1)
                    {
                        temp.CurrentX = (byte)(input.CurrentX - 1);
                        temp.CurrentY = (byte)(input.CurrentY - 1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goto case 4;
                    }
                }
            case 8:
                {
                    if (input.Map[input.CurrentX - 0, input.CurrentY - 1] != 1)
                    {
                        temp.CurrentX = (byte)(input.CurrentX - 0);
                        temp.CurrentY = (byte)(input.CurrentY - 1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goto case 7;
                    }
                }
            case 9:
                {
                    if (input.Map[input.CurrentX + 1, input.CurrentY - 1] != 1)
                    {
                        temp.CurrentX = (byte)(input.CurrentX + 1);
                        temp.CurrentY = (byte)(input.CurrentY - 1);
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        goto case 8;
                    }
                }
        }
        return temp;

    }

    public StepMakerOutput Stepmaker(PathFinderOutput input)
    {
        byte currentX;
        byte currentY;
        //robot útja szabad/ akadályozott pálya esetén
        if (input.Blocked == false)
        {
            currentX = input.NextX;
            currentY = input.NextY;
        }

        else
        {
            StepMakerOutput temp = ModeOffroad(input);
            currentX = temp.CurrentX;
            currentY = temp.CurrentY;
        }

        StepMakerOutput output = new StepMakerOutput(currentX, currentY);
        return output;
    }


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //start és végpontok
        byte startX = 3;
        byte startY = 3;
        byte endX = 99;
        byte endY = 99;


        byte[,] map = MapGenerator();
        map = ObstacleGenerator(map, 20, 80, 25, 40);
        map = ObstacleGenerator(map, 15, 75, 60, 75);


        PathFinderOutput outputP;
        StepMakerOutput outputS = new StepMakerOutput(startX, startY);

        while ((outputS.CurrentX != endX) && (outputS.CurrentY != endY))
        {
            outputP = Pathfinder(map, outputS, endX, endY);
            outputS = Stepmaker(outputP);
        }

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        PictureBuilder(map, e.Graphics);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: When the program enters the infinite loop pause the execution and revise step by step why it does not finish

Comment: I tried to find the problem with breakpoints. How can I pause execution?

Comment: `goto` is generally not recommended.

Comment: Also, no need to explicitly compare to `true` and `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue lies within the way that your case statements fall. The picture you are drawing and your path look like this:

[image: Path Finder]

Now when your path hits the side of the rectangle at 24,33, it calls case 3 which tries to move +1,+1 to 25,34. It can't, so...

```
case 6: +1,+0 (Wall is to the right, so no go)
case 9: +1,-1 (Wall is still to the right, so no go)
case 8: +0,-1 (No wall above so it moves up to 24,32)
```

Now in the next step it determines the shortest path is to move down to 24,33. Then it starts again trying to move +1,+1 to 25,34 creating your endless loop.
You could try using a calculation for choosing the best direction to test instead of just iterating through pre-set directions.

If it can't move to +1,+1 and testing of +1,0 shows it is blocked, it should assume that the next test would be 0,+1 not 0,-1. Instead of gotos you could loop through an array of case comparisons that is created where you set your switcher values. In the case of switcher 3 you could have:

```
byte[] DirectionTester = new byte[] { 3, 6, 2, 9, 1, 4, 8, 7 }
```

This would ensure that the most positive movements would be tested first.

Answer (score 0):

To find out what makes the error, start your program with Visual Studio. When it enters the loop, look on your tool bar for the Pause button (On the menu under Debug => Break All) or set a break point in the area the loops forever.

The program will pause execution. Visual Studio will jump to the current line of code and highlight it in yellow. You can check the current values of all your variables, and use the F10 and F11 keys to advance through your program one line at a time, and confirm that it's working the way you expect.

Eventually, the program will do someone you don't expect. Look at the variables until you understand why. Then stop the program, fix the code so it won't do that any more, and try again. This is how debugging works.

In this case, you've got a bit of a maze of `goto` statements in there. Re-write to not use goto, and I expect you'll find things work better.

Comment: I double checked the goto-s they work as they should, I don't know how could I solve this subtask without them. Break all is greyed out I can't click on it.

Comment: You can't click it until you get in the loop.

Comment: Strange according to this f10 f11 tool it leaves the loop properly.

Comment: Then you pause to make sure what you have inside visual studio is the same code you're running outside visual studio, and if it is, you try again until you can reproduce the problem.

Comment: at                 outputS = Stepmaker(outputP);
line it has the correct value (24,33) but it changes to (24,32) but I don't see what makes this...

Comment: So did you walk through the Stepmaker() function to see what it does? F11 to enter the function from that line, and then F10 to step through each line of the function.

Comment: somehow after it left the cycle it's like it doesn't make the next step, this is strange... Could someone more experienced go through my code? :( After it leaves the ModeOffroad it doesn't go into pathfinder but why...

Comment: It repeats that forever because outputS isn't changing like you think it is. Step through the Stepmaker function using the debugger, like I suggested. This function needs to eventually (if you call it enough) produce a result that will break out of the while condition.

Comment: seems like it goes to 24:32 -> 24:33 ->24:32 -> 24:33 but what makes this behavior hmm... That fancy goto structure should avoid this kind of errors.

Comment: Simply I don't find the problem with outputS just what I wrote above.

Comment: Any suggestion how could I fix that defect you found?

Comment: I'm trying to find it for hours now... How could I fix my code? :(

Comment: Go through the function line by line. Eventually you will find the line that changes it. It's _not_ the `outputS = Stepmaker(outputP);` line. That line shows the results of the `Stepmaker()` function. It's somewhere _inside_ the `Stepmaker()` function.

Comment: outputS = Stepmaker(outputP);  makes the good result. At                 outputP = Pathfinder(map, outputS, endX, endY) the outputS has different value than before. Is that the bug? Or it's normal behavior?

Comment: better if I rewrite the whole thing